# URL is not loading with iframe

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

Our webpage is entirely placed under iframe, each page is set under a common iframe.My issue is once after login,when i navigate to any page through url either through irb or script, the url get passed to the browser but it is  failed to display the concern page.
Do we have any open issue specific to iframe + Watir? Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are saying that when directly navigating to a URL that the content inside an iframe on that page is not displayed? And that this happens only with Watir and not when done manually?

Comment: exactly, you are right. It is working fine manually.

Comment: Can you share the html and the code you are writing that isn't working? Navigating directly to a page should be the same regardless of browser or driver; the only thing I can think is that some state is getting set manually that isn't happening in your test code.